# Edible lollipop sticks for a complicated birthday cake

Tags: baking, cake, chocolate, cupcakes

I'm baking a cake for my sister. Though the cake will be simple. I decided to make chocolate cupcake lollipops. The cupcakes will read out her traits like nice, awesome etc. I need some advice on how to make edible sticks which will be connecting the base cake and the cupcakes.

[image: sticks]

I want them to be edible because long story short she always wondered why is there the point of the stick if its not eatable when she was young.

I also want to know how to prevent the cupcakes from sagging down and dropping on the base cake.

Comment: Can you get pocki where you are?

Comment: If you can't find pocki, there's rolled cookie that you can get in a can ... I just can't think of the name of it.  (it's kinda straw-like, with chocolate on the inside).  And there's also peppermint sticks (candy canes without the bend ... although those might be too slick).

Comment: Isn't the sister of your sister also your sister?? Also, concerning Joe's idea: If you use full sized peppermint sticks (candy canes) you can soak off the red, and be left with just white.

Comment: @Jolenealaska e.g. same mother for first two sisters, but different fathers, other sister is of different mother, but same father as your sister. Often called half-sister. More common than you think!

Comment: Pepperidge Farm's pirouettes!

Comment: How will this question be helpful to future users? It seems like a brainstorming exercise to me, with dozens of answers that can't be objectively ranked.

Comment: @LittleWhiteLithe : thanks, that was the cookie I was thinking of.

Comment: @AirThomas : this could also be useful to entriants in gingerbread house contests (where all items used must be edible).  eg. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7928/67

Comment: I think a good idea would be candy cigarettes. The sticks would be a fair bit thicker than your average lollipop stick, but it could look way more convincing than other options.

Comment: @AirThomas The fact that there's more than one answer doesn't mean it's a bad question. And it will be helpful to future users because future users may want to do something similar; wanting to avoid inedible components is pretty common. The suggestions in the comments need to be in an answer, not comments, but that's not the OP's fault.

Comment: Everyone- I've written up your brainstorms into a Community Wiki, feel free to add any more you can think of.

Comment: @Jefromi I never said it was a bad question. I just don't think it was posed in a way that's very suitable for the format.

Comment: @AirThomas Okay, then more specifically, I don't think it's an *unsuitable* question, I think the fact that there's more than one possible answer is fine (there are specific criteria and the list won't be *that* long), and I think it can be helpful to future readers. If you want to improve it (without changing the intent), go for it, but I certainly don't think that it needs to be closed if it's unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

The brainstorming in the comments has provided numerous examples:

- **[Candy cigarettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy_cigarette)**

  These are likely the most realistic sticks you will find, as they're usually completely white, but fairly soft so use care when attaching the muffin to the top:

  [image: Image of Supersonic Candy Cigarettes]
- **[Pocky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocky) / [Mikado](http://pocky.glico.com/world/mikado.html)**

  These are chocolate covered biscuit sticks, they're much more sturdy but not the right colour:

  [image: Image of Chocolate Pocky]

  There is also a Cookies & Cream flavoured Pocky, marketed as *Pocky Panda*, which is white and the closest resemblance they make. This may require being purchased from the internet though as I'd never heard of them before:

  [image: Image of Pocky Panda]
- Rolled Chocolate Wafer Biscuits

  These are simply tubes of wafer biscuits, typically filled with chocolate, such as [DeBeukelaer Pirouline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirouline) and [Pepperidge Farm Pirouette](http://www.pepperidgefarm.com/ProductDetail.aspx?catID=734):

  [image: Image of a Pirouline]
- [Stick Candy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stick_candy) and [Rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_%28confectionery%29)

  Quite simply sticks made out of candy, I suspect Rock will be less common outside the United Kingdom, but Stick Candy should be simple to find.

  Rock is a hard candy tube up to an inch thick which could support a table, nevermind a cupcake:

  [image: Image of Brighton Rock]

  Stick Candy is basically un-bent candy canes and less thick than rock, though very similar:

  [image: Image of Stick Candy]

Comment: Wow! I thought candy cigarettes had gone the way of the dodo! :) Nice summary, +1, welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: I have had white Mikado (in France). In many places candy cigarettes are no longer sold, whether actually banned or just withdrawn.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but an answer not in the wiki or comments or other answer: **pretzel sticks dipped in white chocolate**.

The white chocolate will be an off-white but if you prefer there are candy melts that are bright white.

Answer (score 0):

Sugarcane sticks would be an idea! They’re edible and sturdy. Sugar cane is sold as accessories for stirring drinks too, I think it’s a company called Hula Girl.